# No Static IP address in Azure Functions when making outbound calls to external parties

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have Azure Durable Functions Application on Consumption Plan that has Orchestrator Function that executes set of Activities. Activity can be writing files to external SFTP server, which allows connection only for whitelisted IPs. Azure Functions does not have Static IP Address, but rather large range of IP addresses, which is not acceptable, since only 1 or few IP Addresses are acceptable by external SFTP server.

How to better mitigate this issue? Is it possible to use Azure Gateway/Azure Api Management or it rather helps for inbound connections and not for Activity Function that will write to External SFTP? Should some kind of Proxy be used?

Comment: Do you need to use functions for this? You're going to have to have a server running somewhere if you want a static IP, acting as a reverse proxy, and I assume the FTP server isn't necessarily scalable. Instead of routing requests through Azure functions, passing through a reverse proxy server, why not send it straight from a normal server? If you want to run a slow or long-running task, maybe consider a webjob.

Comment: Functions are not used just for writing to external SFTP, this Activity is one from many others and works fine without need to have Static IP for their logic. The issue is with calling from large number of Functions being executed at the moment one AppService or VM which becomes a bottleneck

Answer (score 0):

You will need any service that supports a public static ip address. You should compare the price / complexity to change your current solution to one of them.

PS: It worths a mention that at this moment, API Management in Consumption Plan does not accept static ip address.

Comment: I do not want to change current solution since it serverless and highly scalable working well for different activities except one that should have Static IP address. As of now I’ve tried to move writing to external SFTP functionality to VM or AppService Web Api and execute call to AppService or VM which has Static IP address and can write to external SFTP: But limitations are that with Functions I have 1000 Activities executing at the moment and at once they need to call App Service Web Api and I started receiving Timeouts from Web Api

Comment: @OleksandrTedikov, Is the Web API too slow to handle the requests, or is it too "bursty"? If it's too bursty, you can send those requests through a message queue and feed it into the web API so it can consume them at its own pace. However at that point it might be easier to use a reverse proxy.

Comment: Since I make a call from Azure Function activity I have more or less 230 seconds before timeout, so when 1000 requests are made to Web Api at once, it handles these requests, but for example in 5 minutes, so that part of requests times out

Comment: @Slothario unless you're talking about hosting the web api into a VM, the result will be the same, since Azure Functions runs on App Services, which has a range of output ip addresses.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no other nicely managed solutions you can use, one option is dumping the FTP files to blob storage, and sending a message through a message queue containing the file reference to a VM cluster.

Those static-IP VMs can be set to listen to the message queue, retrieve the files from blob storage, and upload them to the external FTP site. If it goes too slowly you can just add more VMs to listen to the queue.

Comment: in case of using VMs who will be listening to message queue? Should it be Windows Service? Or some kind of Web Job deployed to VM?

Comment: @OleksandrTedikov It could be either.